# "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string" in MySQL/Python

Tags: python, mysql, string, select, wildcard

First type is working

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM order_items WHERE (order_work_date between '%s' AND '%s') """ % (_startDate, _endDate)
```

Second type is working

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM order_items WHERE (order_client_company_name LIKE '%s') """ % ("%"+company_Name+"%")
```

Third type have error message "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM order_items WHERE (order_work_date between '%s' AND '%s') and (order_client_company_name LIKE '%s') """ % ((_startDate, _endDate), ("%"+company_Name+"%"))
```

Comment: ‍♂️ Why do you have *two* tuples in your non-working example? You just need one tuple with three elements. More than that though, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You must use the placeholder mechanics of your SQL driver, not do manual string interpolation.

Answer (score 2):

All the arguments to format should be in one tuple:

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM order_items WHERE (order_work_date between '%s' AND '%s') and (order_client_company_name LIKE '%s') """ % ((_startDate, _endDate, "%"+company_Name+"%"))
```

Having said that, it's a bad practice to use string formatting to build an SQL string from arguments, as it's vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should probably look into using bind variables.